# What is a better way to deal with unknown list structures in python?

Tags: python

My python program receives MIDI data from a C library.  Sometimes the data will look like this:

```
[[[[240,0,1,116]]],[[[3,100,8,1]]],[[[107,247,0,0]]]]
```

and sometimes it will include timestamps like this:

```
[[[[240,0,1,116],26738]],[[[3,100,8,1],26738]],[[[107,247,0,0],26738]]]
```

I need the data in an array of bytes, with the timestamp values discarded.  The code I wrote to do this is:

```
        def convertMidiSysex(data):    
            while isinstance(data[0][0], list):
                out = []
                for index, value in enumerate(data):
                    out = out+value
                data = out

            out = array.array('B')
            for i in range(len(data)):
                if isinstance(data[i], list):
                    for j in range(len(data[i])):
                        out.append(data[i][j])
                        if out[-1] == 247:  # 0xF7 is marker to end sysex message
                            return out
```

I can't help feeling that I'm doing this the hard way.  Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: Are you using this code in real-time, or offline?

Comment: What would you like the actual output to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly cleaner way to get what you have now:

```
# the entry below mixes timestamped and non-timestamped inputs
entry = [[[[240,0,1,116]]],    [[[3,100,8,1]]],
         [[[107,247,0,0]]],    [[[240,0,1,116],26738]],
         [[[3,100,8,1],26738]],[[[107,247,0,0],26738]]]

data = array.array('B')
for sublist in entry:
    for item in sublist[0][0]:
        data.append(item)
        if item == 247:
            break
```

Comment: I would say your former code was very non-"pythonic". An interesting reading would be this (part of this) page: http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#use-in-where-possible-1, which says some things about idiomatic (pythonic) ways to accomplish common programming constructs "the right way"in python.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the depth is always consistent:

```
from itertools import takewhile

def convertMidiSysex(data):
    values = takewhile(lambda v: v != 247,
                       (a for x in data for a in x[0][0]))
    out = array.array('B', values)
    out.append(247)
    return out
```

Examples:

```
>>> convertMidiSysex([[[[240,0,1,116]]],[[[3,100,8,1]]],[[[107,247,0,0]]]])
array('B', [240, 0, 1, 116, 3, 100, 8, 1, 107, 247])
>>> convertMidiSysex([[[[240,0,1,116],26738]],[[[3,100,8,1],26738]],[[[107,247,0,0],26738]]])
array('B', [240, 0, 1, 116, 3, 100, 8, 1, 107, 247])
```

Comment: Might want to add an `itertools.takewhile(lambda v: v != 247, ...)` to be consistent with the original code. (And append 247 on the end.)

Comment: @Dougal - Thanks, completely missed that aspect of it.

Comment: The depth is not assumed to be constant.  I'm going to have to take some time to understand this approach.  Thanks...